# Ruby: how to download file with unknown format?

Tags: ruby

I want to download favicon from various urls, so I do this:

```
  require 'mechanize'
  agent = Mechanize.new
  link = 'http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=blog.ycombinator.com/'
  agent.get(link).save "images/pic.png"
```

The problem is that, how do I know  what `http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=blog.ycombinator.com/` return is a `.png`? not `.ico`, not `.jpg`?

Will saving it into different format produce any problem? And how should I save the file accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you receive by a call to `Mechanize#get` is an instance of `Mechanize::Image` object, that has a lot of information about the image itself.

```
▶ got = agent.get link
#⇒ #<Mechanize::Image:0x00000005315e48 ...>

▶ ext = got.response['content-type'].split('/').last
#⇒ "png"

▶ got.save "images/pic.#{ext}"
```

Besides the content type, the returned object has another info to be taken into account, e. g. whether request succeeded.

As @Stefan pointed out in comments, one should use a gem / library to determine a correct extension by MIME-type:

```
▶ require 'rack/mime'
▶ Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.key(got.response['content-type']) 
#⇒ ".png"
```

In this particular case, though, I believe the `case-when` would be sufficiently enough.

Comment: `Content-Type` is the right way, but you should use a gem / library to look up the proper extension for a given MIME type (or you could end up with `.jpeg` and `.x-icon` files)

Comment: Addtionally, when I do `got.save "images/pic.#{ext}`, the file would be renamed into `pic 2` if there exist one with the same name. How could I make it replace the existing one?

Comment: @cqcn1991 `Mechanize` takes care of not rewriting files. I am not sure, if there is a way to instruct it to overwrite existing files, I would go with plain ruby `File.delete(filename) if File.exist?(filename)` before `got.save`.